# how to get values from one node and add it to other node in firebase using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

[image: i want to do like this]

i"m new to firebase my problem is how to get values from one node and add it to other node in firebase using angularjs

as the picture suggest i want to add name, price, quan from values node to users node i try `item.quan` but it"s not adding into node

plunker code: http://embed.plnkr.co/nZWjy1SP08Au6DJmoBYD/preview

my code

```
$scope.addMessage = function () {
        $scope.uu.$add({
            user_name: $scope.user.name,
            user_number: $scope.user.number,
            user_city: $scope.user.address,
            newspaper:item.quan

        });
    };

<li ng-repeat="item in val">

                    <a href="#43">
                        <p class="next-days-date"><span class="day">{{item.text}}</span> <span class="scnd-font-color">{{item.price}}</span></p>
                        <p class="next-days-temperature">{{item.quan}}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Comment: Your code isn't calling `addMessage()` and `item` isn't being passed into that call (it's not in the argument list). That would be the first step. `<a href="#43" ng-click="addMessage(item)"`

Comment: @Kato i did that but it saying item value undefined .. !!!!!.... can you provide plunker demo

Comment: Your plunkr does not bind anything to `$scope.user`, so that means `user_name: $scope.user.name` fails.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i"m getting the value for $scope_user from the input values but I want to know how to get and set values from one node to another